# Grammatical explanation of "I thought"

Tags: grammar

There are many sentences like this:

> This man, I thought, was a man with great manner!

What is this "I thought" part called in grammar?

Comment: I thought it was the subject and predicate.

Comment: I mean like in the whole sentence, like nonessential clause or soemthing of sort.

Comment: It's not nonessential.  Consider *I thought this man was a man with great manner.*  your sentence has the elements in a different order, but the elements have the same function.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it is not about English. It might be on-topic on our sister site Linguistics, however.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.grammar-once-and-for-all.com/punctuation/parenthetical-expressions/ calls it a "parenthetical expression."  They give an example that's similar to your sentence:

> Jumbo, it seems, prefers peanuts in soy sauce.

Comment: a parente thetical?  You are the perfect person to respond with this thesis.  And right on the money! +1.

Answer (score 0):

'I thought' in this parenthetical usage is a reporting clause (compare

> This man, I confided, was a man with great manner.)

It is the syntax involved rather than the need for an overt speech act / writing down that determines this (see [BBC_Learning English Grammar](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv96.shtml) and [Edufind.com English Grammar_Reporting Verbs](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/reporting-verbs/)). Though 'they all refer to people's thoughts' and 'can be used [when communicating] different types of thoughts, beliefs and feelings'.

The *that* must be omitted; it is optional in

> I thought / felt / said this man was a man with great manner.

It is also considered acceptable (if less usual) to use *think* as a quote verb:

> 'This man', he thought, 'was a man with great manner!'

With 'think' rather than a speech-act verb, the inverted commas are optional, so the two usages conflate.